# Restful Authentication with OmniAuth Facebook Authentication routing

Tags: facebook, authentication, rest, omniauth, routes

I installed omniauth for facebook authentication.  Everything works but the routing.
After visiting

- localhost/auth/facebook

I get sent to

- localhost/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQC3aoZVieeY3WSkYbj4VYoBlpMvE8vAsHkXIhP1o_QCIz2olj7vzwHy1cGKshtRdx_hw6fb8Ru6ErZAYPlIUMuW635bJD2_6pQGe659jTGpZx6h6kBZgumj4o4rJyoDwq032liV6jwP8FFTQDEqoXXkL-ArIpulqpFFUdbssvT8_tNtiAQGxdrylRNdj8hYnHA

This does not route to the controller to create anything. Only

- localhost/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQC3aoZ

will send me to create and check that the credentials are invalid.

I am using

```
match '/auth/facebook/callback' => 'auths#create'
```

I am unsure what is wrong and why one works while the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a lot of problems getting this set up too.  It turns out that even though you're hitting "localhost," OmniAuth is feeding facebook a return URL of something else - 127.0.0.1 - for me.  So what you really need is:

App Domain: localhost  (since this cannot be an IP Address)

Site URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000  (since this is the IP Address OmniAuth is passing)

...but Facebook complains that these need to match, which would make it impossible for you to do local testing.  The workaround is to leave the above settings alone and to go to the Mobile Web section, and fill in the "Mobile Web URL" to http://localhost:3000.  This will allow you to get through FB's validations and use the above settings.